# How can I specify binary-only dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a crate with both a binary and a library. The library is extremely light on dependencies, while the binary requires quite a bit more to, e.g., load files or do scoped parallel things.

Currently, I have my Cargo.toml set up like this:

```
[dependencies.kdtree]
path = "../kdtree"

[dependencies]
rand="0.3.0"
rustc-serialize = "0.3"
csv = {git = "https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv.git"}
crossbeam = "0.2"
num_cpus = "0.2"

[lib]
name = "conformal"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "ucitest"
path = "src/bin/main.rs"
```

The only dependencies the library needs are the `kdtree` and `rand`. However, it seems like even if you only build the library, it goes and builds the binary-only dependencies anyway. I've tried using `features` and other tricks like `[[bin].dependencies]` or `[ucitest-dependencies]` (or adding a `dependencies= []` line under `[[bin]]`) that I thought might make them only build for the binary, but I can't find a way.

These aren't enough dependencies to make this a problem, but it's bothering me. Is there a way to narrow down dependencies so they only build for specific binaries?

Comment: If your library and binary are that drastically different, perhaps they deserve two distinct `Cargo.toml` files? You could always put the binary in a subdirectory and use the library from the parent directory (or a released version).

Comment: From the name it seems your binary is only a test, so you could put it under `tests` and use `dev-dependencies`.

Comment: @starblue The name is misleading in the way that programmers normally think about tests, it's for running trials with the library on UCI test data sets and generating things like learning curves.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are several ways to simulate what you want:

---

### 1) Turn the binaries to examples

[Examples](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#examples) and tests are built with `dev-dependencies`, so you could move those dependencies into this section. The library won't depend on them.

```sh
# File structure
conformal/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
        lib.rs
    examples/        # <-- the `ucitest` is
        ucitest.rs   # <-- moved to here
```

```toml
# Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
kdtree = { path = "../kdtree" }
rand = "0.3"

[dev-dependencies]  # <-- move the examples-only dependencies here
serde = "1"
csv = "0.15"
crossbeam = "0.3"
num_cpus = "1"

[lib]
name = "conformal"

[[example]]         # <--- declare the executable
name = "ucitest"    # <--- as an example
```

To run the binary, use:

```
cargo run --example ucitest
```

---

### 2) Optional dependencies with required features

Dependencies can be made [optional](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-features-section), so other crates that depend on your `conformal` library won't need to download them.

Starting from Rust 1.17, binaries can declare they [require](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-required-features-field-optional) certain optional features to be turned on, effectively making those libraries "needed only for binaries".

```toml
# Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
kdtree = { path = "../kdtree" }
rand = "0.3"

serde = { version = "1", optional = true }          # <-- make 
csv = { version = "0.15", optional = true }         # <-- all of
crossbeam = { version = "0.3", optional = true }    # <-- them
num_cpus = { version = "1", optional = true }       # <-- optional

[lib]
name = "conformal"

[features]
build-binary = ["serde", "csv", "crossbeam", "num_cpus"]

[[bin]]         
name = "ucitest"    
required-features = ["build-binary"]     # <--
```

Note that you need to manually pass `--features build-binary` when building the binaries:

```
cargo run --features build-binary --bin ucitest
```

---

### 3) Make the binaries as its own package

You could do whatever dependency management you like when the library and the binary are separate packages.

```sh
# File structure
conformal/
    Cargo.toml
    src/
        lib.rs
    ucitest/          # <-- move ucitest
        Cargo.toml    # <-- into its own
        src/          # <-- package.
            main.rs
```

```toml
# ucitest/Cargo.toml 

[dependencies]
conformal = { version = "0.1", path = "../" }   # <-- explicitly depend on the library
serde = "1"
csv = "0.15"
crossbeam = "0.3"
num_cpus = "1"
```

Comment: The second method seems to be the best practice. We can then easily add some drafting binaries without polluting something else, and don't get the redundant pkg manifest.

Answer (score 31):

These days this is probably best solved with workspaces [[1](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-workspace-section), [2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html)].

The directory structure is as follows:

```
project-root
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── yourlibary
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── src
│   └── main.rs
└── target
```

The top-level `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[package]
name = "yourprogram"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["You <you@example.com>"]

[workspace]

[dependencies]
yourlibrary = { path = "yourlibrary" }
```

`yourlibrary` `Cargo.toml` file:

```ini
[package]
name = "yourlibrary"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["You <you@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
```

The `Cargo.lock` file as well as the `target` directory is at the project root directory and is shared by all the components in the workspace. Workspace components are inferred automatically from dependencies with locak path, but can be specified manually as well.

Each component with its `Cargo.toml` file can still be published separately on crates.io

Comment: Can `yourlibrary` share code with `yourbinary` when using workspaces?

Answer (score 14):

This is [not implemented yet in Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1982).