# Can I make a Rust bin executable that uses test module

Tags: testing, rust

I have some utility functions in `tests/utils/mod.rs` that are used by my integration tests, but I also want to create a testing binary that isn't run as part of `cargo test` but can use the functions in `tests/utils/mod.rs`. It's a utility that is useful for manual testing, but it only makes sense to run it manually; not using libtest.

The only solution I can think of is to put `tests/utils/mod.rs` in its own crate, but I'd really like to avoid that because publishing multi-crate workspaces to crates.io is [a real pain](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1565). Another option would be to just move `tests/utils/mod.rs` to `src/test_utils/mod.rs` but that is a bit gross.

Is there a better solution? Maybe something using `harness` somehow?

Comment: Have you thought about using [`#[path]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute)

Comment: Aha nice one! `#[path]` works great. There's a slight issue in that `bin` programs can't have their own dependencies, but I worked around it by making it an example instead of a `bin` [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46017284/265521). That has another slight downside in that examples aren't built by default, but I can live with that.

Comment: I also though about examples, so I wrapped it up in a full-blown answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your statement of "examples aren't built by default", I mean they are _not_ built via `cargo build` but your tests aren't built either. And actually this is a good thing, if the crate is a library. On the other hand, `cargo test` *does* build examples by default, they just aren't executed.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant - things in `bin` are built by `cargo build` but examples aren't. Correct behaviour for actual examples, but my tool isn't *really* an example. It's not a big deal though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a library crate with the following set up, for instance:

```
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   └── lib.rs
└── tests
    ├── foo.rs
    └── utils
        └── mod.rs
```

You can add an executable that is compiled but not run via `cargo test` as an *example*, and then use the `#[path]` attribute to point to your `utils` module.

For example, you can add a `bar` example:

```
└── examples
    └── bar.rs
```

with the following code:

```rust
// using the testing utilities
#[path="../tests/utils/mod.rs"]
mod utils;

fn main() {
    // do something useful with `utils`
}
```

Notice, the `#[path]` attribute, which includes the `utils` module from the
integration tests.

And you can conveniently run it manually with:

```sh
cargo run --example bar
```

Also, you can add additional dependencies for `bar.rs` below `[dev-dependencies]` in `Cargo.toml`.