# Can I config a build script for specific binary with Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My project structure is something like this:

```
├── build_bin_a.rs
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── crates
│   ├── some-crate-a
│   ├── some-crate-b
│   └── .... #etc
├── src
│    ├── bin
│    │   └── some_bin_a.rs
│    │   └── some_bin_b.rs
│    └── lib.rs
└── ...
```

And I need to configure a build script for only one binary target. In this case I need to configure `build_bin_a.rs` build script for `src/bin/some-bin-a.rs` binary target.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'configure a build script' does it need different settings for that single target? Do you want it to run only for that target?

Comment: exactly I want to execute this build script only for that single target. I mean, I don't want the build script to run unless I build that binary target.

Comment: This question is about dependencies, but the solutions are similar to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35711044/6274355

Comment: thanks probably the closest thing to what I need is to turn the binary as its own package, although it would not be ideal because I do not want to complicate more the structure of my project, but for now I think it works for me.

Comment: @al3x Can you please stop rolling-back the tag edits? [tag:cargo] IS THE WRONG TAG to use for the Rust package manager. You should use [tag:rust-cargo] instead. Consult the tag descriptions if you need more convincing. Continuing to do so can be seen as vandalism, which is not allowed even on your own posts.

Comment: I've temporarily locked your posts to prevent further edits. The cargo tag does not apply to rust at all. There is an appropriate tag which has been added to your questions. If you disagree with this or have different opinions on tag usage, please bring them to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for a community discussion. As it stands, however, you are using an objectively incorrect tag and actively working against community consensus which violates our [disruptive use](/conduct/disruptive-use) policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [issue #1430](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1430), not supported currently. Your best bet is to put the binary in a different package.